# Transform rotation does not cover the ends of layout

Tags: html, css

My code is as shown below:

```css
.test {
    position: relative;
    top: 1080px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">this is test</div>
```

With this code, I get strip like this:

[image]

But I want the strip to be like this:

[image]

Comment: The expected outcome, I believe, is not a magic of rotation but merely combination of `border-bottom` of above element and `border-top` of the yellow strip element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `transform: skewY` instead:

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  color: white;
}

.orange {
  background:orange;
}
.orange span {
  transform: skewY(10deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">first div</div>
<div class="test orange"><span>second div</span></div>
```

> Change the value of the `top` based on your need. I didn't use the `1080px` so there will be no scroll in this example...

#### update

Also added an example on how to "align" a text back to the normal alignment inside a skewed element.